# FoxPro ODBC Driver Error "Unable to Create Temporary Work Files"

Tags: asp-classic, odbc, visual-foxpro

I have an application written in ASP Classic and connecting to a FoxPro database which intermittently throws this error message, found in the IIS log file:

14|80004005|[Microsoft][ODBC Visual FoxPro Driver]Unable to create temporary work files.

The line referenced is a SELECT statement against the FoxPro database.  The error does not occur every time this particular SELECT statement is run.

The ever-helpful [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa976055%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) concerning this error suggests that the problem is either due to permissions or to disk space.  Permissions are at least semi-functional because the problem doesn't always happen.  Disk space is also not a problem as there is enough free space on the drive (8GB) proportional to the size of the database in question (about 500MB).

What else can I look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the FoxPro ODBC driver cleaning up after itself?

Look in your TEMP folder (defined by the `%TEMP%` environment variable, in my case), and you may see a large number of files matching the expression `[A-Z0-9]{8}\.TMP` (e.g. `LVAK00AQ.TMP`).

Per this ancient tome, [FIX: TMP File Errors If ALTER TABLE Runs Same Time As ODBC DLL](ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/misc1/DEVELOPR/FOX/KB/Q185/6/55.TXT):

> Visual FoxPro and the VFP ODBC driver both use the same naming
>   convention and algorithm for temporary (.tmp) file creation. If both
>   programs run concurrently, there is a conflict in the processes
>   attempting to access the same file or same file name. This conflict
>   creates different error messages.
>
> Visual FoxPro 5.0x uses a tempfile naming scheme based on the system
>   clock. These names are generated for internal use and many times the
>   filename is never actually created on the disk. However, there are
>   many circumstances when FoxPro does create the temporary file on disk,
>   so the name generation scheme could cause two processes or two
>   instances of the run-time in the same process to generate the same
>   temporary file name. If both processes try to create a temporary file
>   on disk later, only the first one succeeds.

In my experience, the file naming pattern is based on a small unit of time, and with the alphanumeric scheme limited to 8 characters, it will start again from 0 within a short period of time (not sure if hours or days).

If the temp file needs to be written to disk, and the file already exists from a previous execution, then instead of overwriting the previous file, the driver will throw the error "Unable to create temporary work files".

Answer (score 0):

Have you given folder and folder contents change permissions to IUSR_machinename & IWAM_machinename?